# Fab button not working properly with Snackbar

Tags: android, kotlin, native, floating-action-button, snackbar

I am facing problem in Android, [image: Here is the demo.]
when snackbar pops up, fab button not going up, rather its keeps moving up and down. Below is my Snackbar code.
[Note: This behaviour observed only API level below 30, above API 30 its moving up properly]

Below is my Snackbar code.

```
Snackbar.make(view,"Item Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("UNDO") { viewModel.onUndoDeleteClick(event.task)
        }.show()
```

```
My Layout Arch. like:
<CoordinatorLayout>
<AppbarLayout>
.
.
</AppbarLayout>
<ConstraintLayout>
.
.
.
</ConstraintLayout>
<SwipeRefreshLayout>
<NestedScrollView/>
<RecyclerView/>
</SwipeRefreshLayout>
<FloatingActionButton/>
</CoordinatorLayout>

Any suggestion will be helpful, thanks.
```

Comment: Can you try with a different library version? The library for the android views? Also, it is a good ide to write down the dependency versions.

Comment: Here are the libraries i am using:                                                           
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'                                                 
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.4"

Comment: The view used in Snackbar is fragment view, meanwhile, I am trying different versions and views. Thanks.

Comment: I think the FAB has an anchor property, have you try that?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried, and working fine, but the setAnchorView() will move the Snackbar top of FAB, but I want it in the bottom only.

Comment: My problem is occurring only in API below 30. And for 30 and above it's working fine. So trying to find out.

Comment: This custom class to set translation attribute worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65371110/floating-action-button-not-floating-with-snackbar-if-anchorview-set-within-coord   Thank you @cutiko, for your suggestions.